# mysql/java charset issue

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue while storing some special character values into db.

For e.g. if I am adding following values to any textbox,

```
Езикова abc
```

it is storing the values as

```
??????? abc
```

inside db. I have `UTF-8` at every possible places.

refereed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789203/tapestry-charset-problem) link, but no success/.

Comment: For background - check all the points raised here - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added parameter to the database url :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

and everything is working. :)