# UTF-8 encoding issue with Tapestry

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, tapestry

I have an application already running on a server with Tomcat 6 / Java 6 ( with no encoding error ).

The application is doing a GET on an URL and receives a XML with informations as a response.

The informations are displayed in a page with tapestry ( 5.0.18 ).

The goal is to upgrade to Java 7 / Tomcat 7.
I have an encoding issue on this new application.

From my XML I have fields like this :

```
<email>mickaël@xxx.com</email>
```

In my Java Debug I have this :

```
email=mickaël@xxx.com
```

I am displaying the email like this :

```
${message:user-email-field-label}: ${Profile?.email}
```

And finally, in my view, I have :

```
Mes coordonnÃ©es : mickaÃ«l
```

So, I did an installation on my local with Java 7 / Tomcat 7. The problem is still here. 
I downgraded to Java 6 / Tomcat 6 and the problem still remains ( and it is not in the running app ).

Concerning the encoding :

- All my .properties are encoded in UTF-8
- The response header from my page is : Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
- I have tried to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to my JVM
- I have tried : [Tapestry: character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789203/tapestry-character-encoding-issue)
- I have tried : http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5Utf8Encoding

But still, looks like my email is interpreted with ISO-8859. The title from the .properties as mis-interpreted aswell. My datas that are not displayed with Tapestry have no problems.
Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936846/java-tomcat-utf-8-encoding-issue

Comment: Tried, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Encoding issues have a wide range of potential causes. You don't seem to mention html headers so it might be as easy as adding the following header to your HTML to tell your browser what to use.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

As a side note, your Tapestry version is pretty old. Released in [december 2008](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.nl/2008/12/tapestry-50-final-release-5018.html). You might also like to upgrade to a later version.

Comment: My header is well set with charset=UTF-8, and it is not my call to upgrade Tapestry, i'll have to deal with this version ...